# How to get clientcontext using ContextHub api

Tags: maven, aem

I'm using AEM6.2. I've set user data into clientContextHub. Now I need to get those clientcontextHub values into my component WCMUsePojo class. I've written as below :

```
 ContextHub contexthub = getSlingScriptHelper().getService(ContextHub.class);
 Resource res =   this.getResourceResolver().getResource("/etc/cloudsettings/default/contexthub");
 stores = contexthub.findStores(res);
```

1. Is this the correct approach to get the clientContextHub value?
2. When I deploy this code, I see my bundle is not active because 
   `com.adobe.granite.contexthub.api,version=[3.0,4) -- Cannot be resolved.`
   If the corresponding dependency is added in the pom.xml, the build fails as the required jar file is not present in adobe repository  http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/granite :

   ```
   <dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.granite</groupId>
          <artifactId>com.adobe.granite.contexthub.commons</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.36</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: you don't need that dependency, its available in 6.2.0 uber jar.

Comment: This is also I thought but I see the version dependency error.